# Get name and value with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this simple form:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="20$" /> book
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="30$" /> plane
```

**PHP:**

```
$product = $_POST['product'];
foreach($product as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

**Note:**
The user can choose one or two ... products.

**Question:**
I want to know if there is a solution to get the `name` too, like adding an ID class or something ..

*Basically I cant get the `name` attribute because I didn't sent it with the form.*

Comment: Side note: for better accessability, use a label: `<input id="book" ... /><label for="book">book</label>`

Comment: You *did* send the name attribute. It is `product[]`. :)

Comment: I mean the name of each choose (plane or book)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the missing information to your POST-parameters:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[book]" value="20$" /> book
<input type="checkbox" name="product[plane]" value="30$" /> plane
```

You can iterate over it like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $name => $value) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: it should be noted the first variable is the array key. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option presented by elusive, but it seems that in this case you're passing the price from the client to the server. That might allow people to fraud. They could with only a little hacking send another (lower) price. If you just send 'book' and redetermine the price on the server, this won't be a problem.

If you choose that path, you can just put the product ('book') in the value:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="book" name="product[]" value="book" />
<label for="book">book</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="plane" name="product[]" value="plane" />
<label for="plane">plane</label>
```

Comment: Yes But I want to the value (price) too :)